# Construction Of the Imperial forces

Tags: star-wars

Are there any canon references or direct quotes to give examples of how the Empire funded its mass production of weapons and assault vehicles? I'd assume they have taxes like the governments in today's age but surely that's not enough money to fund a Galactic Army.

I recall from the [Force Unleashed](https://www.starwars.com/games-apps/star-wars-the-force-unleashed) video game that there was even a production facility for mass-producing Star Destroyers.

The big question is; Where are all the Imperial Credits coming from to fund all this?!

Comment: “I'd assume they have taxes like our governments in todays age. Surely that is not enough money to fund a galactic army though.” Why not? It’s a galaxy’s worth of taxes. That’s a lot of cash.

Comment: That is true. just wishful thinking on my part i guess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Canonically, I can't think of any description of the way in which the Empire was funded however there's repeated mention of the

> "The taxation of trade routes to outlying star systems"

in Phantom Menace which presumably the Empire continued to enforce.

Again, in the original "Attack of the Clones" [script](http://www.scenebyscene.net/ii/aotcscript.txt), Dooku makes reference to the benefits of joining the Separatists being;

> "lower taxes, the reduced tariffs, and the eventual abolition of
>   all trade barriers"

I think we can reasonably assume that the Empire continued to benefit from these funds.

Furthermore, the people involved in the "Victory Celebration" at the end of ROTJ seem happy that the Empire has been defeated so the implication would be that they've suffered subjugation, presumably financial as well as cultural.

[image: Victory Celebration ROTJ]

Outside the original films, there's extensive mention of the [Imperial Taxation Bureau](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Taxation_Bureau) in the Star Wars game book; "[The Far Orbit Project](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Far_Orbit_Project)" which describes a body responsible for setting and collecting taxes throughout the Empire.

In addition, the Empire was [deeply involved](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Decree_A-SL-4557.607.232) in the procurement and management of [slave labour](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_Decree_A-SL-4557.607.232) involving a wide variety of species including the Agorffi, Wookiees, Yuzzem, Talz, Mon Calamari, Givin, Quarren, Chromans, Ugnaughts, Mustafarians, Gamorreans, Gungans, Kaminoans and Kallidahins as well as the sexual enslavement of Twi'leks girls.

Comment: +1 and this is the best answer. You used all insights and information from the series to answer my question, which is what i was looking for. thank you!

Comment: Yep, Richard - you beat me to it. And keep in mind that part of the subjugation was not only excessive taxation, but also that the Empire was notorious for arresting people and seizing their assets. Basically, if you were rich (or even just well-off) and NOT in the Empire's pocket, you could pretty much count on storm-troopers knocking down the door at some point.

Answer (score 9):

> Surely that is not enough money to fund a galactic army though.

USA funds the largest military-industrial AND space program in the world by taxes. I think that the question is based on incorrect assumption.

---

Empire taxes:

- Profits of corporations (you can see examples in X-Wing novels where some guy was running an off-the-books business that Isard found out about)
- Trade (see your taxation of trade routes), which was how Germany's many states made tons of money in Middle ages.
- Populace

  Wookieepedia says (uncited):

  > After the Galactic Republic changed to the Galactic Empire, tax laws were consolidated into the Imperial Revenue Codes and placed under control of the Imperial Taxation Bureau. The Empire significantly raised taxes around the galaxy, and the Ghorman Massacre saw a protest against Imperial taxes brutally crushed.

  However, the cite can be found in the article on Mon Mothma's [Declaration of Rebellion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Declaration_of_Rebellion), which contains:

  > You have raised taxes without the consent of those taxed;

---

To top that off, empire also uses slave labor (Wookiees, Kessel prisoners) to minimize costs.

Comment: +1 this is all good information. the fact that you tied in the modern worlds economy and such is a great example. I knew the U.S had those big projects I was just hoping there were other ways they funded besides printing it out and taxes. Wishful thinking i guess

Comment: +1 Well said. However, I can't resist to laugh at the quote of the Declaration of Rebellion. Compared to the other items, "genocide", "racism" and "murder", it seems that "taxes" is a case of [Arson, Murder and Jaywalking](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArsonMurderAndJaywalking) :P